# Object Identification failed in Coded UI, while executing a method in a loop

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have created a generic method which can be used to search for records in our AUT.

Now I have a scenario that I need to run my code multiple times. So I have created a loop and tried to execute. The first iteration it runs without any issues and page gets closed. Re-opened the page and all the controls get loaded, but object identification failed during the second iteration.

initializing the HtmlEdit object as below:

```
HtmlEdit medit = new HtmlEdit(objSearchPage);     
medit.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "1$SearchText", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);     
medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.TagName] = "INPUT";     
medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Edit";
```

The playback failed while trying to enter text on 'medit' box during the second iteration. First iteration it succeeded: `medit.Text = searchItem;`

Comment: Does the problem occur without your code? I ask because questions about code requires you to post your code. If the question is about coded UI and your code is irrelevant then make that clear.

Comment: initializing the HtmlEdit object as below,                                            HtmlEdit medit = new HtmlEdit(objSearchPage);
medit.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "1$SearchText", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);  medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.TagName] = "INPUT";
medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Edit";                                      The playback failed while trying to enter text on 'medit' box during the second iteration. First iteration it is success - medit.Text = searchItem;

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["control.Exists" within a loop works for first time and not for second time in coded ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526163/control-exists-within-a-loop-works-for-first-time-and-not-for-second-time-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If your browser window is opening and closing during the iteration, you'll need to include the initialization code in the loop or use the AlwaysSearch setting.

```
foreach(var thing in thingsToDo)
{
    HtmlEdit medit = new HtmlEdit(objSearchPage);     
    medit.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "1$SearchText", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);     
    medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.TagName] = "INPUT";     
    medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Edit";

    // use medit now and it will work
}
```

or

```
HtmlEdit medit = new HtmlEdit(objSearchPage);     
medit.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "1$SearchText", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);     
medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.TagName] = "INPUT";     
medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Edit";

// I'm not sure this will work because the browser window is different
medit.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

@MPavlak is close to the money. What I think we may be forgetting is you'll also have to reinitialize your parent control (objSearchPage). Make sure that it exists and is found before searching for medit.

```
foreach(var thing in thingsToDo)
{
    var objSearchPage = new UITestControl(); //you can also just reinitialize here if it's been previously declared.
    objSearchPage.SearchProperties.Add("yourPropertyHere");

    HtmlEdit medit = new HtmlEdit(objSearchPage);     
    medit.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "1$SearchText", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);     
    medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.TagName] = "INPUT";     
    medit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Edit";
}
```